# RDLC -- Any way to allow user input directly on them similar to how PDF documents work?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-input, rdlc, rdl

Basically, as the title says... is there any way to have user input directly on the report? I know in Adobe PDF documents you can have textboxes that a user can type directly into.

Comment: You Can Pass the User Value as parameter in RDLC. Search with "passing parameters in rdlc report" Tag in Google.

Comment: Yea, but I'm more concerned with with input directly on the visible form just like how PDFs do it.

Comment: Do you mean the Find Text box in Adobe Reader?. If you have the Image Please Share it. Its very helpful to find your requirement?.

Comment: No, I mean the input fields in a PDF. http://www.pdfconverter.com/images/pdftips/fill-pdf-forms-01.jpg << see how the PDF has fields the user can fill in?

Comment: +1 Very interesting... I didn't see before. I wish you to get this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. An RDL/RDLC is a report.

Comparing an RDL/RDLC to the way Adobe PDF operates is like so:

With AdobeLivecycle Designer you can create a PDF with form elements in it for the user to fill out. Then, when the user is finished and previews/saves the document it generates an actual PDF.

This would be akin to designing a UserControl/Window/Page in a way that it's layout resembles your RDL/RDLC. Then, when the user clicks a "Save/Preview" button on your control it sends the necessary info to the ReportViewer which generates a report.

PDF FORM = UserControl/Window/Page
PDF = RDLC

Comment: Is any possible in Crystal or Other Reports?.

Comment: No idea... I've never used anything outside of RDL/RDLC and Adobe LiveCycle.

Comment: Thanks., but i am willing to know this,